# Processing for Android and regular input apps

Tags: java, android, processing

Processing has Android support and it seems to be pretty awesome from my 10 minutes of playing with it.  But I would like to make a regular (nongraphics) application like a twitter feed reader or something.  So is there something like Processing that can do regular apps?  Besides Titanium...

Basically I am looking for anything that will make coding for android easier, processing was so easy to get working that I was very happy with it, but it is for graphics only.  Titanium didn't give me the same wow factor and it isn't open so that kind of takes away from it.  What other tools are out there?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but Processing is a tool for creating graphics, images, animations, etc. What would you use it for in a non-graphical application?

Comment: That is what I am saying.  Is there something similar to processing that can generate regular input applications.  Titanium kind of fits the build, but I was looking to see if there was something similar.

Comment: What do you consider "similar to processing" to be? The syntax looks a bit like Java to me.

Comment: Do you mean, something that would allow you to write a console application in a meta-language that sits above Java, similar to how Processing is a language which is really just converted to Java? What it is you are actually asking here is vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to give you the answer you are looking for and some advice.
Processing can do ANY of the things you are thinking about doing.  If you want textboxes etc, you can use the [Control P5 library](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/).  It's great.  If you are an expert at Processing and just want to port over your Processing code to android, Processing for android is great.

But that's not what you want to do.  You want to write an application.  And you want to write it on Android.  There are frameworks designed to give you a leg up in [writing cross-platform mobile apps](http://distractable.net/coding/iphone-android-web-application-frameworks/), but nothing is going to make writing an android application easier than learning Java and learning how the android stack works.  It's actually really well designed and easy to follow once you start grokking "intents" and "bundles".

At the end of the day, you might even want to scale back a little further.  Are you trying to write an application that needs to be used without internet access or that uses super special phone APIs?  If you aren't, maybe you should try just writing your app as an html5 css3 website.

Answer (score 1):

You can do plenty of input based stuff with processing. The original mouse events work as specified, except pass touches, but you can also access things like pressure and multiple fingers down. The hardware keys are also supported.

Comment: When I say input I mean textboxes and the like.